# Error “No rule to make target …”

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to run travis test,but I get the following error.

I checked my files and directories, all files are exist.

I think my mistake in cmake file, but I can't find it.
Maybe someone can help me?

make[1]: *** No rule to make target `CMakeFiles/test.dir/all', needed by`CMakeFiles/Examples.dir/all'.  Stop.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared instead of static library" OFF)
option(BUILD_TESTS "Build tests for webdavclient" ON)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/ /sources)
add_library(test STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sources/client.cpp tests/main.cpp)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()

if(UNIX)
    set(DEPENDS_LIBRARIES ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARY} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
elseif(MSVC)
    set(DEPENDS_LIBRARIES ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARY} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ws2_32)
endif()

add_executable(Examples ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/examples/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Examples ${PROJECT_NAME} ${DEPENDS_LIBRARIES})

if(BUILD_TESTS)
    enable_testing()
    file(GLOB ${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST_SOURCES tests/*.cpp)
    add_executable(init ${${PROJECT_NAME}_TEST_SOURCES})
    target_link_libraries(init ${PROJECT_NAME} ${DEPENDS_LIBRARIES})
    add_test(NAME init COMMAND init "-s" "-r" "compact" "--use-colour" "yes")
endif()
```

Comment: Have you run CMake? Do you invoke your Makefile in the build directory? Is your generator really for MAkefiles? Does the Makefile exits? Where is "the following error"?

Comment: it's github project for https://travis-ci.org

Comment: it's error in travis logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command `enable_testing()` among other things creates target `test`. But you already have library target with the **same name**. This confuses CMake. For avoid this, *rename library target*.

Also, it is not recommended to have target name same as the project. So, *rename project too*.

Comment: Thank you, one more question, I have directory in github project "tests" with "init.cpp" file, which include file "include/client.hpp". File "client.hpp" use boost library, you can see in my code that I'm trying to start test with file "init.cpp", but unfortunately I have error in travis logs init.cpp:(.text+0x8d4): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::extension() const'

Comment: `find_package(Boost)` organizes interaction *only with core part* of the Boost. For use *filesystem* component, you need to inform `find_package()` about that: `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem)`.

Comment: *it is not recommended to have target name same as the project.* Why?

Comment: @PengheGeng: I read about situations that some CMake generators may behave incorrectly with a project and a target named identically. However, I cannot give a link to such discussions.